# Too Many Open Files Issue with MQ9 where we connect to Qs using com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnectionFactory

Tags: java, ibm-mq

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Too many open files
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource.getConnection(JtdsDataSource.java:186)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource.getXAConnection(JtdsDataSource.java:99)
        at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource.createPooledConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:341)
        at org.springframework.boot.jta.bitronix.PoolingDataSourceBean.createPooledConnection(PoolingDataSourceBean.java:110)
        at bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool.createPooledObject(XAPool.java:283)
        at bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool.grow(XAPool.java:391)
        at bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool.getInPool(XAPool.java:371)
        at bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool.getConnectionHandle(XAPool.java:123)
        at bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool.getConnectionHandle(XAPool.java:91)
        at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:258)
        ... 112 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:288)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:251)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:331)
        ... 123 common frames omitted
```

In spring boot application which is running on linux we are using IBM MQ9 with MSSQL 2017
Using `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnectionFactory` to connect to 4 different Qs and processing high volume of data.

We have tried increasing the soft limit and hard limit to 8192 but still we get this error around
4k+ above value for command
`lsof -u <ouruser> | grep "jsk"  | wc -l`

Also tried with `XX:+MaxFDLimit` but no use.

I have tried almost everything that I could find for similar issues suggested in stackoverflow and the issue still persists.

If I run a simple java program like below in the same linux box , I can see this value going till 16380 and then throwing Too Many Open files exception

```
public class tooMany {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException {

        System.out.println("Trying to reproduce");
        try {
            for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++) {
                System.out.println("Opening the file");
                FileInputStream leakyHandle = new FileInputStream("some file to read");
                System.out.println("file is opened");
            }
            System.out.println("Method Should Have Failed");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("too many open files");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unexpected exception");
        }
    }
}
```

but in my application its failing after 4k+ ..

Any help is much needed as this issue is been dragging for long now. The concern is we could not reproduce this in lower environment and seeing this twice a week in PROD..

Output of `ulimit -a`

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 770116
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 8192
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 16384
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: can you share connection pool configuration? also it would be that transactions are not commited thats why maybe connections are not released.
you can check this in thread dump that multiple connections might be waiting on something.

Comment: I guess you are focusing in the wrong problem. The problem is not why your "tooMany" class uses 16k+ File descriptors, but why your connection pool is reaching so many open connections.